# Exception in Boto3 - botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

When trying to connect to a database with this python code to test the connection.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

for b in s3.buckets.all():
   print b.name
```

I am getting this error thrown at me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "boto3_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    for b in s3.buckets.all():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/resources/collection.py", line 83, in __iter__
    for page in self.pages():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/resources/collection.py", line 161, in pages
    pages = [getattr(client, self._py_operation_name)(**params)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 310, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 385, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 111, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 140, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 213, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 226, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 209, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 250, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 273, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 313, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 222, in __call__
    return self._check_caught_exception(attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 355, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.us-east-5.amazonaws.com/"
```

The strange part is that the connection was working earlier in the day and then at it stopped working the same thing happened to me yesterday at the same time so I am assuming it is a network configuration issue. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361173/python-boto3-connection-error-with-no-apparent-cause) is the only one that is similar the solution the original poster stated was to unset both HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY which I attempted but it did not work.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have configured AWS env incorrectly. Check your `~/.aws/config` file. You must have configured it incorrectly as us-east-5 which is an invalid region. Change it to `us-east-1`. Or run `aws configure` command again and specify the correct region.

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
```

Comment: Thank you for some reason I thought region meant time zone instead of datacenter haha.

Comment: @helloV In my case I have the region configured correctly(ap-south-1) in the config file but still the error shows up. what else could be the cause?

Comment: @helloV `botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.ap-south.amazonaws.com/"` this is the error message.

Comment: @helloV Just now changed it to `ap-south` in the config file but still got the same error. could there be any other reason  ?

Comment: @vishal.k you should set the config like: `region=ap-south-1`

Comment: @helloV well actually it was like that before, anyhow I have changed it to the way exactly you have mentioned(even without spaces) but still i get the same error.

Comment: @vishal.k Most likely Boto3 is getting the region from some other place. Check if region is configured in env variable `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` If it is set, unset it and try again. See: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html

Comment: I have no region configured at `~/.aws/config` and `echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` returns nothing. However, as it worked before, I found it weird that this can be the issue... Any other idea on how to debug this?

Comment: @JAgustinBarrachina what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: The same as the title question. However, the issue was that the server was down. Not a problem locally. Sorry forgot to reply.

Answer (score 4):

We got this issue (with status code 500 returned) out of the blue.

After some research we found out that there was some infra update on AWS which caused the service to be down.

You can find the current down\up services per zone and upcoming down time [here](https://status.aws.amazon.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Got the same boto3 error.

In my case a `config.lock` and `credentials.lock` were created behind the scenes:

[image]

Removing them solved the issue.

Comment: Could you develop further? How to check if that happened and how to remove it?