# boto3 Route53 complains Could not connect to the endpoint URL:

Tags: python, boto, amazon-route53, boto3

I was trying to get some Route53 automation working with boto, and noticed that this tiny boto3 (version 1.3.1) example:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('route53')
print client.list_hosted_zones()
```

blows up with a complaint about:

```
  File "... venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 356, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://route53.us-east-1e.amazonaws.com/2013-04-01/hostedzone"
```

while this similar boto2 (using version 2.38.0) code seems to work fine:

```
from boto.route53.connection import Route53Connection
r53_conn = Route53Connection()
print r53_conn.get_all_hosted_zones()
```

and prints out a dictionary of info about my hosted zones. If I attempt to coax boto3 into using the endpoint [suggested by Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) (even though it seems boto3 should know how to do this by default...), like this:

```
client = boto3.client('route53', endpoint_url='https://route53.amazonaws.com')
```

I get this error:

```
  File "... venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 572, in _make_api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the ListHostedZones operation: Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'us-east-1e'.
```

Is there something particular I need to do to teach boto3 how to talk to Route53 correctly, and why is it that boto2 seems to know how to do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this answer [Exception in Boto3 - botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685446/exception-in-boto3-botocore-exceptions-endpointconnectionerror) 
all you need to do is to configure your `~/.aws/config` file.
That's seems like you didn't configure it or configured incorrectly.

Comment: Hm, guess that was it: I had `region = us-east-1e` instead of `region = us-east-1` in ~/.aws/config, and it seems that was causing this error. Thanks!