# Exception in Botocore while trying to read a files from AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I've been hitting an exception which previously had never rose up. I am trying to read a file stored in S3 with boto3. Something like this:

```
session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=my_aws_access_key_id,
        aws_secret_access_key=my_aws_secret_access_key,
        region_name="us-east-1",
    )
s3 = session.resource("s3")
bucket = s3.Bucket("my_bucket_name")
mystring = bucket.Object(my_object_key).get()["Body"].read()
... some other code ...
```

Right where it should allocate the string in the mystring variable, I get the following:

```
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://<my_bucket_name>.s3.amazonaws.com/<my_object_key>"
```

- I have tried to retrieve the file using the AWS CLI with the same
  credentials that I'm giving boto3 and it does work fine.
- I am setting specific region name and credentials so as to avoid aws config issues.
- The endpoint URL given in the exception is the correct URL of the object.
- I have tried with any other objects in S3 and it's not working.
- I checked for changes in environment variables as explained in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361173/python-boto3-connection-error-with-no-apparent-cause), to no avail
- I also checked all suggestions in this [other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685446/exception-in-boto3-botocore-exceptions-endpointconnectionerror) without results

This error came out of the blue. Yesterday it was working fine and today it isn't, no changes in the source code.

Comment: Is it possible that your bucket is not in the region "us-east-1"?  The CLI might work because your config references a different region.

Comment: **Side-note:** It is considered poor security to store AWS credentials in your source code. Instead, use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command to store your credentials in a configuration file. The AWS CLI and boto3 will automatically look in that file for credentials. You can then simply use: `s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-1')`

Comment: @CoinGraham The bucket is in the right region. and it does match with aws config. It was working fine and then it was not, no changes were made neither in the CLI config nor to the code. I really am at a loss.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yeah, it's not specified as a string, the credentials are not anywhere in the code per se. It actually reads from a secret or an environment variable. I just wrote it like that for simplicity. I am not letting it use the configuration file because i have several profiles configured and i need it to use a specific one for development.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created a bucket in `us-east-1`
- Uploaded a file to us-east-1
- Ran this code:

```py
import boto3
s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3", region_name='us-east-1')
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket("my-bucket-name")
mystring = bucket.Object('my-object-name').get()["Body"].read()
print(mystring)
```

It successfully printed the contents of the object, suggesting that your code is not to blame. Perhaps there is another configuration in your system that is affecting it?

I then tried this code from [Any method to get s3 endpoint url for a given region? · Issue #1166 · boto/boto3 · GitHub](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1166):

```py
import botocore.loaders
import botocore.regions

loader = botocore.loaders.create_loader()
data = loader.load_data("endpoints")

resolver = botocore.regions.EndpointResolver(data)
endpoint_data = resolver.construct_endpoint("s3", "us-east-1")
print(endpoint_data)
```

It returned:

> OrderedDict([('hostname', 's3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'), ('signatureVersions', ['s3', 's3v4']), ('variants', [OrderedDict([('hostname', 's3-fips.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'), ('tags', ['dualstack', 'fips'])]), OrderedDict([('hostname', 's3-fips.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'), ('tags', ['fips'])]), OrderedDict([('hostname', 's3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'), ('tags', ['dualstack'])])]), ('dnsSuffix', 'amazonaws.com'), ('partition', 'aws'), ('endpointName', 'us-east-1'), ('protocols', ['http', 'https'])])

Not sure if that helps, but it's something for you to compare against.

My `boto3.__version__` is showing `1.24.38`.