# botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError from inside Mac Docker container

Tags: python, macos, amazon-web-services, docker, boto3

I've recently started getting an EndpointConnectionError (after a long timeout) when attempting to contact DynamoDB from inside a Docker container running on Mac. The same code and setup has previously worked fine.

Here's some sample code:

```
>>> from boto3 import resource
>>> r = resource('dynamodb')
>>> table = r.Table('Users')
>>> table.put_item(Item={'id':'987987'})
```

My ~/.aws/config:

```
[default]
output = json
region = us-east-1
```

Code I'm using to rebuild and restart the container (from Mac OS):

```
#!/bin/sh
docker-machine ssh default "docker ps | awk 'NR > 1 {print \$1}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker kill"
docker build -t <image_name> .
docker-machine ssh default "docker run -p 80:80 -v /var/datenight_secret:/var/www/.aws <image_name>" &
```

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 518, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 258, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 537, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 117, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 146, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 219, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 227, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 210, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 274, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 314, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 356, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

I get the same behaviour (hangs for a long time, then same stacktrace) when I try us-east-2 or eu-west-1. The same config and credentials files work fine on a us-east-1 EC2 host or from my Mac OS.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361173/python-boto3-connection-error-with-no-apparent-cause) I've ensured that HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY are both blank.

Python version is Python 3.4.3.

Comment: Can you access the internet from the container? `ping www.google.com`

Answer (score 1):

Running `docker-machine stop default; docker-machine start default` fixed the problem. How profoundly unsatisfying - I thought that was going to be an interesting problem that would teach me something about networking.