# Not able to access AWS S3 buckets

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

All,
I am getting following error, accessing s3 using boto3

```
 EndpointConnectionError: 
 Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/"
```

I followed following steps.

1. Created AWS account with billing.
2. Created a user with group policy: AmazonS3FullAccess
3. Generated a access key for that user, and using in code below:

   ```
   from boto3 import client
   from pandas import read_csv

   acc_key = read_csv("accessKeys.csv") # access key file
   ACCESS_KEY = acc_key.loc[0,"Access key ID"]
   SECRET_KEY = acc_key.loc[0,"Secret access key"]

   client_access = client(
   's3',
   aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
   aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,)

   client_access.list_buckets() # giving the error here
   ```

   Tried adding `region_name` in `client` method, but of no use.
   Am i missing anything?

Comment: Where are you running this script from? Does that machine have internet access?

Comment: yeah, it has internet access. I am working on the script from office workstation.

Comment: Do you have any of the following environment variables set: `HTTP_PROXY` or `HTTPS_PROXY`? Refer this stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361173/python-boto3-connection-error-with-no-apparent-cause

Comment: @Krishna, tried now with the same configuration in my home it's working.Access can be a issue i guess.

Comment: What is the output of this command on your office workstation? `dig s3.amazonaws.com`

Comment: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/' indicate you did not specify valid region, you must specify the exact region you want to to use . Just put the region_name in the code and we will know what's wrong (perhaps typo?).